# How to pass a multivariate vector valued function (with variable length output) to aggregate

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate

I have a data frame in R that I want to aggregate. The summary function that I want to apply to each subset is a custom function that takes several variables (columns) as input, and returns a vector or list of **variable length**. As an output, I would like to have a data frame with a column of the grouping variable, and a single other column containing the output vector (of varying length).

To give a mock example, suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame( particle = c(rep("X",5),rep("Y",3),rep("Z",4)),
 time = c(1:5,1:3,1:4), state = c(c("A","A","B","C","A"),c("A","B","B"),
 c("B","C","A","A")), energy = round(runif(12,0,10)))

> df
   particle time state energy
1         X    1     A      9
2         X    2     A      8
3         X    3     B      7
4         X    4     C      5
5         X    5     A      0
6         Y    1     A      1
7         Y    2     B      7
8         Y    3     B      7
9         Z    1     B      3
10        Z    2     C      9
11        Z    3     A      5
12        Z    4     A      6
```

I would like to obtain for each particle a list of the energy they had every time they changed state. The output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
>
   particle      energy
1         X      c(9,7,5,0)
2         Y      c(1,7)
3         Z      c(3,9,5)
```

To do so, I would define a function like the following:

```
myfun <- function(state, energy){
   tempstate <- state[1]
   energyvec <- energy[1]
   for(i in 2:length(state)){
      if(state[i] != tempstate){
         energyvec <- c(energyvec, energy[i])
         tempstate <- state[i]
      }
   }
   return(energyvec)
}
```

And try to pass it to aggregate somehow

The two data structures I tried for this are data.frame and data.table.

In data.frame, using a custom function that returns a vector seems to give the correct output format I am looking for, that is where the output column is really a list, and each row contains a list with the output of the function. However, I can't seem to pass several columns to the function when aggregating this way.

With a data.table, the aggregation is easier to do when considering a function of several variables. However, I can't seem to obtain the output I'm looking for. Indeed,

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,myfun(state, energy), by= Particle]
```

only returns the first element of energyvec (instead of a vector), and

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,as.list(myfun(state, energy)), by= Particle]
```

doesn't work as the outputs don't all have the same length.

Is there an alternative way to go to accomplish this?

Thank you very much in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame( particle = c(rep("X",5),rep("Y",3),rep("Z",4)),
                  time = c(1:5,1:3,1:4), state = c(c("A","A","B","C","A"),c("A","B","B"),
                                                   c("B","C","A","A")), energy = round(runif(12,0,10)))

# Hard-code energy to make this reproducible
df$energy <- c(9, 8, 7, 5, 0, 1, 7, 7, 3, 9, 5, 6)

df %>%
  group_by(particle) %>%
  mutate(
    changed_state = coalesce(state != lag(state, 1), TRUE)
  ) %>%
  filter(changed_state) %>%
  summarise(
    string = toString(energy)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   particle string    
#>   <fct>    <chr>     
#> 1 X        9, 7, 5, 0
#> 2 Y        1, 7      
#> 3 Z        3, 9, 5
```

I'd run each line of the pipe individually. Basically, create a `changed_state` variable by checking if the "this" state matches the last state `lag(state, 1)`. Since we only care when this happens, we `filter` where this is `TRUE` (a more verbose line would be `filter(changed_state == TRUE)`. The `toString` function collapses the rows of energy as desired and we are already "grouped" by `particle`.

Comment: I 'borrowed' your sample data for my answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! That works. I simply changed the `toString` function to `list()` instead since it makes it easier for me to manipulate it afterwards (in particular, the length is the number of state changes). It is worth noting that the other solutions below also work very well using `data.table`

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` approach

**sample data**

```
#stolen from JasonAizkalns's answer
df <- data.frame( particle = c(rep("X",5),rep("Y",3),rep("Z",4)),
                  time = c(1:5,1:3,1:4), state = c(c("A","A","B","C","A"),c("A","B","B"),
                                                   c("B","C","A","A")), energy = round(runif(12,0,10)))

df$energy <- c(9, 8, 7, 5, 0, 1, 7, 7, 3, 9, 5, 6)
```

**code**

```
library( data.table )
#create data.table
dt <- as.data.table(df)

#use `uniqlist` to get rownumbers where the value of `state` changes, 
# then get these rows into a subset
result <- dt[ data.table:::uniqlist(dt[, c("particle", "state")]), ]

#split the resulting `energy`-column by the contents of the `particle`-column
l <- split( result$energy, result$particle)
# $X
# [1] 9 7 5 0
# 
# $Y
# [1] 1 7
# 
# $Z
# [1] 3 9 5

#craete final output
data.table( particle = names(l), energy = l )
#    particle  energy
# 1:        X 9,7,5,0
# 2:        Y     1,7
# 3:        Z   3,9,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, .(energy=.(.SD[, first(energy), by=.(rleid(state))]$V1)), by=.(particle)]
```

output:

```
   particle  energy
1:        X 9,4,6,9
2:        Y     2,9
3:        Z   7,6,1
```

data:

```
set.seed(0L)
DF <- data.frame( particle = c(rep("X",5),rep("Y",3),rep("Z",4)),
    time = c(1:5,1:3,1:4), state = c(c("A","A","B","C","A"),c("A","B","B"),
        c("B","C","A","A")), energy = round(runif(12,0,10)))
DF
#    particle time state energy
# 1         X    1     A      9
# 2         X    2     A      3
# 3         X    3     B      4
# 4         X    4     C      6
# 5         X    5     A      9
# 6         Y    1     A      2
# 7         Y    2     B      9
# 8         Y    3     B      9
# 9         Z    1     B      7
# 10        Z    2     C      6
# 11        Z    3     A      1
# 12        Z    4     A      2
```